# android user entering birth date validation

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating android library. In lib there is screen with 3 edittexts. User enters day, month and year. I have to find out is user older than 18.

I don't have any documentation for error handling or anything for this task. So I did something on my own.
My function for checking is user older than 18 is like this:

```
 fun isUserAdult(birthDay: String, birthMonth: String, birthYear: String): Boolean {
    val year = Integer.parseInt(birthDay)
    val month = Integer.parseInt(birthMonth)
    val day = Integer.parseInt(birthYear)
    val c1 = Calendar.getInstance()
    c1.set(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0)

    val c2 = Calendar.getInstance()
    var diff = c2.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    if (c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) > c2.get(Calendar.MONTH) ||
        (c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == c2.get(Calendar.MONTH) && c1.get(Calendar.DATE) > c2.get(
            Calendar.DATE
        ))
    ) {
        diff--
    }

    return diff >= 18
}
```

My error handling is based just on my logic. It looks something like this:

```
fun isDataValid(birthDay: String, birthMonth: String, birthYear: String): Boolean {
    return !(birthDay.startsWith("0") && birthMonth.startsWith("0") && birthYear.startsWith("0") || Integer.parseInt(
        birthMonth
    ) > 12 || Integer.parseInt(birthDay) > 31 || Calendar.getInstance()
        .get(Calendar.YEAR) < Integer.parseInt(birthYear) || Integer.parseInt(birthYear)< 1880)
}
```

This looks fine on the first look but I believe there are a lot of cases when considering date that makes my code error-prone.

Is there any other way to do this or has anyone some advice on how to improve my way?

Comment: Do you want to show the user the exact info why the passed date was invalid? If not I would simply add try/catch for `Integer.parseInt` and `c1.set` and catch the relevant exceptions

Comment: You could better use a `DatePicker` or `MaterialDatePicker`

Comment: Yes I know. But design is made like this and I am just an android developer, not a designer :D